# JQuery onclick not running for link on page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

```
<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
    <p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"></p>
    <span id="122"></span>
    <h3 class="ui-li-heading"></h3>
    <p class="ui-li-desc"></p>
    <p class="ui-li-desc"><a class="ui-link">Report</a></p>
</li>
```

So I dynamically add a bunch of these list items to my JQuery mobile page when the page loads. As the page is up, I am also refreshing them every 5 seconds.

I want to perform a click function if you click the `Report` link though (this might get a little bit wonky with when you do it though?), so I have this code to do it:

```
$('a.ui-link').click(function(){
    alert('report');
});
```

But I'm not getting any alert when I click it.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `live()` method to attach the handler to dynamically added elements that match the selector:

```
$("a.ui-link").live("click", function(){ alert("report"); });
```

If the `a.ul-links` are the children of a certain element with an `id`, you can use the `delegate()` method instead for better performance:

```
$("#parent").delegate("a.ui-link". "click", function(){ alert("report"); });
```